# ASP.NET editing values in a nested GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I'm trying to get my head around editing values in a GridView inside another GridView. I'm able to edit the values on the first GridView, but when I hit "Edit" on the child GridView, nothing happens except for a postback.

My GridView structure is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gwProperties" runat="server" Width="100%"
                        onrowediting="gwProperties_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        DataKeyNames="Name,IsActive" 
                        onrowcancelingedit="gwProperties_RowCancelingEdit" 
                        onrowdeleting="gwProperties_RowDeleting"
                        ShowFooter="True" onrowupdating="gwProperties_RowUpdating">
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#20334F" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />   
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="green" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <Columns>                                  
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Ret" UpdateText="Gem" CancelText="Annuller" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Navn" SortExpression="Name" />                                  
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aktiv" SortExpression="IsActive" Visible="true">                                       
                                <ItemTemplate> 
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsActive").ToString())) ? "Aktiv" : "Inaktiv" %>'></asp:Label>                                                                        
                                 </ItemTemplate>      
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbIsPropertyActive" Checked='<%# Bind("IsActive") %>' />
                                 </EditItemTemplate>                              
                            </asp:TemplateField>                                
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="100%">
                                            <asp:GridView DataKeyNames="StreetName,Zip,City,Country" runat="server" ID="gwAddresses" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSource='<%#Eval("Addresses") %>' OnRowEditing="gwAddresses_RowEditing">
                                                <Columns>                                                        
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vejnavn">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStreetName" Text='<%# Bind("StreetName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStreetName" Text='<%# Bind("StreetName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Ret" UpdateText="Gem" CancelText="Annuller" />                                                        
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Zip" HeaderText="Postnummer" SortExpression="Zip" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="By" SortExpression="City" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Land" SortExpression="Country" />                                                

                                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td colspan="100%">                                                                        
                                                                    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gwStreetNumbers" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSource='<%#Eval("StreetNumbers") %>' OnRowEditing="gwAddresses_RowEditing">
                                                                        <Columns>                                                                
                                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Nummer" SortExpression="Number" />
                                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Letter" HeaderText="Bogstav" SortExpression="Letter" />

                                                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td colspan="100%">
                                                                                            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gwPrivateLeases" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSource='<%#Eval("LeaseTypes.PrivateLeases") %>' OnRowEditing="gwAddresses_RowEditing">
                                                                                                <Columns>
                                                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aktiv">
                                                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIsLeaseActive" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsActive").ToString())) ? "Aktiv" : "Inaktiv" %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TakeoverDate" HeaderText="Overtagelsesdato" SortExpression="TakeoverDate" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Floor" HeaderText="Sal" SortExpression="Floor" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Side" HeaderText="Side" SortExpression="Side" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Regulating" HeaderText="Regulering" />
                                                                                                    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Prospect" HeaderText="Prospekt" />
                                                                                                    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FloorPlanDrawing" HeaderText="Plantegning" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LeasingPeriod" HeaderText="Lejeperiode" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SquareMetre" HeaderText="Kvadratmeter" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Rent" HeaderText="Husleje" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NumberOfRooms" HeaderText="Antal værelser" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ACConsumption" HeaderText="A/C forbrug" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PaymentInAdvance" HeaderText="Forudbetalt leje" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Termination" HeaderText="Opsigelse (antal måneder)" />
                                                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Møbleret">
                                                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIsFurnished" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsFurnished").ToString())) ? "Ja" : "Nej" %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Husdyr">
                                                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIsFurnished" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsAnimalsAllowed").ToString())) ? "Ja" : "Nej" %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Altan">
                                                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIsFurnished" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("HasBalcony").ToString())) ? "Ja" : "Nej" %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delevenlig">
                                                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIsFurnished" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("CanBeShared").ToString())) ? "Ja" : "Nej" %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TypeOfRental" HeaderText="Lejemålstype" />
                                                                                                </Columns>
                                                                                            </asp:GridView>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td colspan="100%">
                                                                                            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gwBusinessLeases" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSource='<%#Eval("LeaseTypes.BusinessLeases") %>' OnRowEditing="gwAddresses_RowEditing">
                                                                                                <Columns>
                                                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aktiv">
                                                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIsLeaseActive" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsActive").ToString())) ? "Aktiv" : "Inaktiv" %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TakeoverDate" HeaderText="Overtagelsesdato" SortExpression="TakeoverDate" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Floor" HeaderText="Sal" SortExpression="Floor" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Side" HeaderText="Side" SortExpression="Side" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Regulating" HeaderText="Regulering" />
                                                                                                    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Prospect" HeaderText="Prospekt" />
                                                                                                    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FloorPlanDrawing" HeaderText="Plantegning" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MinimumSquareMetre" HeaderText="Kvadratmeter min." />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MaximumSquareMetre" HeaderText="Kvadratmeter max." />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="YearlyRentPerSquareMetre" HeaderText="Årlig leje pr. m2" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ACYearlyOperationalCostPerSquareMetre" HeaderText="Årlig drift pr. m2" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Deposit" HeaderText="Depositum" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MonthsOfPaymentInAdvance" HeaderText="Forudbetalt leje (antal måneder)" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="VATAgreements" HeaderText="Moms" />
                                                                                                   <asp:BoundField DataField="MonthsOfTermOfNotice" HeaderText="Opsigelsesvarsel" />
                                                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TypeOfRental" HeaderText="Lejemålstype" />
                                                                                                </Columns>
                                                                                            </asp:GridView>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                        </Columns>
                                                                    </asp:GridView>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                 </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>                                           
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Sorry for the wall of text - it's quite massive ;-) Actually it's four nested gridviews, but I guess when I'm able to edit the first nested, I can just do the exact same for the other child gridviews.

I have tried something like this in the .cs file:

```
protected void gwAddresses_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gwAddresses = (GridView)sender;
    gwAddresses.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    FillGridView();
}
```

But it does nothing. Is this possible at all? I have found some excellent articles about this, but I simply can't get it to work :-/

I have a strange feeling that I'm using the wrong control for this.

My object structure is as follows:

```
- Property
    - List<Address>
          - Address object: List<StreetNumber>
                - StreetNumber object: List<LeaseTypes>
                       - LeseTypes object: List<PrivateLease> and List<BusinessLease>
```

So basically it's a five step deep structure which I need to bind and make editable on the frontend in my ASP.NET solution.

This is giving me a serious headache, so I'd be ever greatful if anyone has got a small hint on how to achieve this!

Thanks in advance!

- Bo